# Can I set the content of a jQuery text() Method to be another .text() method?

Tags: jquery, html

I have content in a `<p class='firstLine'>` and I want to display it inside a `<p class='secondLine'>`
Is it possible to do this on one line in jQuery without using a function within the text() method?
Something like `$('p.secondLine').text($('p.firstLine'));`

Comment: *"...without using a function within the text() method? Something like $('p.secondLine').text($('p.firstLine'));"* makes no sense, not least because that *is* using a function (`$`) within the `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can set the `innerText` of one element as the `innerText` of another element.

You didn't call the `text()` in your code. `$('p.secondLine').text($('p.firstLine'));`.

```
$('p.secondLine').text($('p.firstLine').text());
//                                     ^^^^^^^
```